# JQuery sending post data to file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, http-post

I've been looking around stack for a while on how to do this, however for me it just doesn't want to work and I'm starting to get clueless.

What I want to achieve is for data in a textfield (ckeditor) to be saved in an html file. I am trying to achieve this by handling saving the file in edit_docInc.php.

What I do is I try to run JQuery to get data from edit_doc.php into edit_docInc.php, and when it's done I want to refresh a DIV in edit_doc.php with a file named show_doc.php and slide to it in a slider.

This is what I got so far:
edit_doc.php

```
$docfile = "./documents/" . $cursus['name'] . "/" . $docfilename . ".html";
echo("<h1>Editing Document: " . $rows['name'] . "</h1>
<a id='slider-editbtn'>Edit</a> | <a id='slider-viewbtn'>Preview</a>");
echo("<div id='slider'>
    <div id='slider-content'>
        <div id='left'>
            <form name='editdoc' id='editdoc' action='" . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . "' method='post'>
            <input type='hidden' name='docid' value='" . $docfile . "' />
            <textarea name='mainEditor' id='mainEditor'>");
                include($docfile);
            echo("</textarea>
            <a class='button save' id='save'>SAVE DOCUMENT</a>
            <script>
                CKEDITOR.replace('mainEditor');

                $('#save').click(function (e) {
                    $.ajax ({
                        type: 'POST',
                        url: 'edit_docInc.php',
                        data: { 'form' : $('#editdoc').serialize()},
                        success: function(ex) {
                            $('right').load('show_doc.php');
                            $('#slider-viewbtn').addClass('active');
                            $('#slider-editbtn').removeClass('active');
                            $('#slider-content').animate({left:'-=940px'}, 400);
                            sliderPos = 2;
                            alert('loaded!');
                        }
                    })
                });
            </script>

        </div>
        <div id='right'>");
            include('show_doc.php');
        echo("</div>
    </div>
</div>");
```

edit_docInc.php

```
echo("<script>alert('got into script!');</script>");
$docfile = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['docfile']);
$data = $_POST['mainEditor'];
$handle = fopen($docfile, 'w') or die("Can't open the file, please contact an administrator.");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);
echo("<div id='alert success'><span>Success:</span> File has been successfully saved!</div>");
```

show_doc is too simple to show really.
Btw edit_docInc.php doesn't alert me, so it doesn't even get into edit_docInc.php

Please if anyone knows the answer, it's greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is what you are sending: data: { 'form' : '#editdoc').serialize()},

Comment: that's how I'm supposed to do it right?

Comment: But the way you are receiving those values, example $_POST['docfile'] .....that var doesnt match on you current web form...maybe its $_POST['docid']

Comment: Oops, my mistake. But sadly that's not why it's not working :(. It just doesn't seem to go into my edit_docInc.php at all

Answer (score 0):

I am an idiot, it seems like the page I was trying to get into was in the same map of edit_doc.php (inc), however edit_doc.php is an include in documents.php which was outside the inc map and therefore the URL I needed to use was inc/edit_docInc.php instead of just edit_docInc.php.